# how to traverse xml document using linq to xml?

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a following XML document

```
<name>Avi malhotra</name><age>55</age>
```

I need to change into following document

```
<Column>name</column>
<Value>Avi Malhotra</Value>
<Column>age</Column>
<Value>55</Value>
```

How to do using `linq` to `xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XDocument source = XDocument.Parse("<person><name>Avi malhotra</name><age>55</age></person>");

XDocument x = new XDocument(
    new XElement("person",
        new XElement("Column", "name"),
        new XElement("Value", source.Element("person").Element("name").Value),
        new XElement("Column", "age"),
        new XElement("Value", source.Element("person").Element("age").Value)));
```

Now you can call `x.Save("path");` to save the created XDocument.

Please note that I have added a "person" element, otherwise the XML would not be well-formed, because there would be no root element.